# Finding Out If Datetime Is In a Specific Time Interval Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I find out if a datetime column in my table is in a specific hour interval (e.g 13:07 - 15:15) and in a specific day (e.g Thursdays) in a  SQL select statement?

Thanks,

Comment: with all the answers here showing you the different ways of filtering on datetime values, I think you have enough info to write the code yourself. At this point you're just asking "please write the code for me, I don't want to bother trying to understand it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Day of week and start/End hours as arguments

```
declare @tbl table ( datecol datetime )

declare @startHour int
declare @endHour int
declare @specificDay varchar(10)

set @startHour = 13
set @endHour = 15
set @specificDay = 'Thursday'

insert into @tbl select getdate()
insert into @tbl select dateadd(hh, 1, getdate())
insert into @tbl select dateadd(n, 10, getdate())
insert into @tbl select dateadd(dd, 2, getdate())

select * from @tbl 
where  DATENAME(dw, datecol) = @specificDay
and datepart(hh, datecol) >= 13 
and datepart(hh, datecol) <= 15
```

**EDIT:**

```
declare @tbl table ( datecol datetime )

declare @startHour varchar(10)
declare @endHour varchar(10)
declare @specificDay varchar(10)

set @startHour = '13:05:00'
set @endHour = '15:30:00'
set @specificDay = 'Thursday'

insert into @tbl select getdate()
insert into @tbl select dateadd(hh, 1, getdate())
insert into @tbl select dateadd(n, 10, getdate())
insert into @tbl select dateadd(dd, 2, getdate())

select * from @tbl 
where  DATENAME(dw, datecol) = @specificDay
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), datecol,8) >= @startHour
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), datecol,8) <= @endHour
```

If time has hours and minutes parts only like '13:05' then change it like this

```
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), datecol,8) >= @startHour
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), datecol,8) <= @endHour
```

Comment: What if my hours were 13:15 and 15:07?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * From #t

Where DatePart(hour, [date]) >=10 
and DatePart(hour, [date]) <= 11

And DatePart(minute, [date]) >= 15
And DatePart(minute, [date]) <= 45

and Datename(dw,[date]) = 'Thursday'
```

Comment: What about minutes? For example My hour interval is "13:07-15:16"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225976(SQL.80).aspx) keyword. Such as `... WHERE MyDate BETWEEN Date1 and Date2`

Comment: But I need only for example Mondays and between 13:05-15:30?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following syntax:

```
DECLARE @FromTime DATETIME
DECLARE @ToTime DATETIME
SET @FromTime = '2010-09-02T13:00:00'
SET @ToTime = '2010-09-02T15:00:00'

SELECT Something
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateField >= @FromTime
    AND DateField < @ToTime
```

You could use BETWEEN but I usually prefer the above instead as BETWEEN is *inclusive* e.g. in this example, using BETWEEN would include records where the time is 15:00:00.000

Comment: But I need only for example Mondays and between 13:05-15:30